# using schemes to route users from website to iOS app?

Tags: ios, safari, url-scheme

I have been able to add schemes to my app's today widget and spotlight search **successfully**, but now my question is about unifying schemes from website to app,
I'm dealing with a website with links like `www.mysite.com/itemType/itemID`
I need it to redirect users to the app if they have it installed, but with a scheme like `myAppName://itemType/itemID`

q1- can schemes do that? (I'm targeting iOS 9+)

q2- do I have to change anything in the website source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible with universal links, and activitycontinuation, already added it into my app, works great to add seamless transition between website and app.